# Error "no route to host" sshing to an instance launched by openstack autopilot

Tags: networking, juju, openstack

I've taken a long path installing Opensatck Autopilot till reached at this point. The problem now is that after a floating ip association to the new instance I'm unable to ssh to it from where I'm used to sshing to all physical nodes. When I poking around in a [***report***](https://oldbrowser.files.fm/u/qsz8qm68) generated by `juju status` in juju inner environment it seems some of services have a current status of either blocked or error. Like

```
neutron-gateway/0:

workload-status:       
current: blocked

message: 'Services not running that should be: neutron dhcp-agent, neutron-vpn-agent'
```

The log file `/var/log/neutron/dhcp-agent.log` on machine 0 which neutron is placed also is [here](https://oldbrowser.files.fm/u/zm4cvc8a). It says something about "Timeout in RPC method". Actually most of network related services are not working properly as it declared when I ran `neutron agent-list` command on a node Network services are deployed, including "open vswitch agent".

Another rather less important problem Ibe experienced is that when attempting to deploy juju-gui in inner juju environment I received this error:

```
ERROR cannot load cookies: file locked for too long; giving up: cannot acquire lock: open /home/ubuntu/.go-cookies.lock: permission denied
```

I'm totally helpless please anyone who know where should I begin debuging lift a finger and help

Comment: The permission denied error it could be because the user trying to acquire the lock is not the "ubuntu" user.

Comment: Well first thank you, your hint helped. I changed the user to "ubuntu" but then it complained that `error: cannot load ssh client keys: mkdir /var/lib/landscape/juju-homes/2: permission denied` so I changed it to "root" and it worked (hopefully it wont have any side effects). now I have juju-gui installed in internal juju environment. But still bewildered how to solve the network issue for instances!!

Comment: The blocked status should not affect ssh. Are you trying to ssh inside the lxc? That might only be possible from where the inner environment is bootstrapped. None the less did you try starting the neutron dhcp-agent, neutron-vpn-agent services manually?

Comment: No, I try to ssh from my local machine in public network. Any way regarding your advice for manually starting "neutron dhcp-agent", I tried `$ service neutron-dhcp-agent start` on the machine that nuetron-gateway service is running and I got this error `start: Rejected send message, 1 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.9" (uid=1000 pid=99077 comm="start neutron-dhcp-agent ") interface="com.ubuntu.Upstart0_6.Job" member="Start" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination="com.ubuntu.Upstart" (uid=0 pid=1 comm="/sbin/init ")` . Any opinion what should I do next?

Answer (score 0):

Well it took lots of time inspecting different logs and running many command and also seeking help from real human being (since virtual world didn't stretch any hand) until I came across the `neutron-ovs-cleanup` service log which was error-ridden with

> `ImportError: cannot import name deploy`

Then the quick guide given in this [page](https://ask.openstack.org/en/question/11458/keystone-all-importerror-cannot-import-name-deploy/) did the rest. Well it was the incompatible version of this Python library (PasteDeploy) I guess that made the service fail and consequently led to other related networking services failure as well. So I ran `pip uninstall --yes PasteDeploy && pip install 'PasteDeploy>=1.5.0'` as instructed on the page above and all of a sudden it worked :-)